# How do I figure the ID of an item in my fixtures file using minitest?

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5, primary-key, minitest, fixtures

I'm using Rails 5 with minitest.  How do I know, in my test file, what the ID of one of my the items in my fixtures file is?  I have the following schema

```
  create_table "lines", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "route_long_name"
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "system_type"
    t.string  "color"
    t.string  "onestop_id"
    t.string  "vehicle_type"
    t.string  "wheelchair_accessible"
    t.string  "bikes_allowed"
    t.index ["onestop_id"], name: "index_lines_on_onestop_id"
    t.index ["route_long_name"], name: "index_lines_on_route_long_name"
  end
```

Then in my test/fixtures/lines.yml, I create this fixture

```
one:
  id: "1"
  name: "line1"
  color: "green"

So in my minitest test, I try this

  test "get show page with valid line id" do
    test_line_id = "1"
    line = Line.find_by_id(test_line_id)
    puts "inspect1: #{line.inspect}"
    assert_not_nil line

    get line_url(line)
    line = assigns(:line)
    puts "inspect2 #{line.inspect}"
    assert_equal test_line_id, line.id
    assert_response :success
  end
```

But the line

```
 assert_equal test_line_id, line.id
```

dies with teh error

```
Expected: "1"
  Actual: "980190962"
```

So how do I figure out the ID of teh item in my fixtures file?

Comment: why you are using "1".? Use 1 instead because rails by default store id as integer value. Use byebug right after line 3 to check whether you are able to get line by id or not? "line = Line.find_by_id(test_line_id)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do it that way.

If all you want is to make sure you are getting the URL for a valid line... then you can just get any line at all. You don't need to get it by id eg:

```
 test "get show page with valid line id" do
    # Get any line - it doesn't matter which
    line = Line.first
    assert_not_nil line

    get line_url(line)
    line = assigns(:line)
    assert_equal test_line_id, line.id
    assert_response :success
  end
```